# MD5 VHDL pipeline

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am trying to implement a 3-stage MD5 pipeline according to [this link](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441980793-c1.pdf). In particular the algoritms on page 31. There is also another [document](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/ipsjtrans/2/0/2_0_15/_pdf) which describes data forwarding. This is done in an FPGA (Terasic DE2-115). There is no schematics in this project, only VHDL code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity md5core is
    port (
        CLOCK_50        : in std_logic;
        SW              : in std_logic_vector(17 downto 17)
    );
end entity md5core;

architecture md5core_rtl of md5core is
type r_array is array(0 to 64) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
constant R        : r_array := ( x"07", x"0c", x"11", x"16", x"07", x"0c", x"11", x"16", x"07", x"0c", x"11", x"16", x"07", x"0c", x"11", 
                                 x"16", x"05", x"09", x"0e", x"14", x"05", x"09", x"0e", x"14", x"05", x"09", x"0e", x"14", x"05", x"09",
                                 x"0e", x"14", x"04", x"0b", x"10", x"17", x"04", x"0b", x"10", x"17", x"04", x"0b", x"10", x"17", x"04",
                                 x"0b", x"10", x"17", x"06", x"0a", x"0f", x"15", x"06", x"0a", x"0f", x"15", x"06", x"0a", x"0f", x"15",
                                 x"06", x"0a", x"0f", x"15", others => x"00");

type k_array is array(0 to 66) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
constant K        : k_array := (x"d76aa478", x"e8c7b756", x"242070db", x"c1bdceee",
                                x"f57c0faf", x"4787c62a", x"a8304613", x"fd469501",
                                x"698098d8", x"8b44f7af", x"ffff5bb1", x"895cd7be",
                                x"6b901122", x"fd987193", x"a679438e", x"49b40821", 
                                x"f61e2562", x"c040b340", x"265e5a51", x"e9b6c7aa",
                                x"d62f105d", x"02441453", x"d8a1e681", x"e7d3fbc8",
                                x"21e1cde6", x"c33707d6", x"f4d50d87", x"455a14ed",
                                x"a9e3e905", x"fcefa3f8", x"676f02d9", x"8d2a4c8a",
                                x"fffa3942", x"8771f681", x"6d9d6122", x"fde5380c",
                                x"a4beea44", x"4bdecfa9", x"f6bb4b60", x"bebfbc70",
                                x"289b7ec6", x"eaa127fa", x"d4ef3085", x"04881d05",
                                x"d9d4d039", x"e6db99e5", x"1fa27cf8", x"c4ac5665",
                                x"f4292244", x"432aff97", x"ab9423a7", x"fc93a039",
                                x"655b59c3", x"8f0ccc92", x"ffeff47d", x"85845dd1",
                                x"6fa87e4f", x"fe2ce6e0", x"a3014314", x"4e0811a1",
                                x"f7537e82", x"bd3af235", x"2ad7d2bb", x"eb86d391", others => x"00000000");

type g_array is array(0 to 64) of integer range 0 to 15;
constant g_arr      : g_array := (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
                                          1, 6, 11, 0, 5, 10, 15, 4, 9, 14, 3, 8, 13, 2, 7, 12,
                                          5, 8, 11, 14, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 2,
                                          0, 7, 14, 5, 12, 3, 10, 1, 8, 15, 6, 13, 4, 11, 2, 9, 0);                                               

type w_array is array(0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal W            : w_array;

constant AA        : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"67452301";
constant BB        : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"EFCDAB89";
constant CC        : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"98BADCFE";
constant DD        : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"10325476";

signal res_A    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00000000";
signal res_B    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00000000";
signal res_C    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00000000";
signal res_D    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00000000";

type in_str_t is array(0 to 5) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
constant in_str    : in_str_t := (x"68", x"65", x"6c", x"6c", x"6f", x"6f");

type pad_str_t    is array(0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal pad_str    : pad_str_t;

type state_t is (start, padding, init_w, state_1, state_2, state_3, state_4, done);
signal state    : state_t;

signal a, b, c, d, f    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00000000";
signal i                : integer range 0 to 64 := 0;
signal g                        : integer range 0 to 15 := 0;
--signal tmp_b              : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal akw                  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal ak                   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal b_tmp                : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

    --tmp_b <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(b) + rotate_left(unsigned(a) + unsigned(f) + unsigned(K(i)) + unsigned(W(g)), to_integer(unsigned(R(i)))));

    pipe_p : process(CLOCK_50, SW, a, b, c, d, i)
    begin
        if SW(17) = '0' then
--          ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(2)) + unsigned(BB));
--          akw <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(W(0)) + 1 + unsigned(K(2)) + unsigned(BB));
            b_tmp <= BB;
        elsif rising_edge(CLOCK_50) and state = state_1 then
            if i = 0 then
                ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(0)) + unsigned(a));
            elsif i = 1 then
                ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(1)) + unsigned(a));
                akw <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(W(0)) + unsigned(ak));
            elsif i = 2 then
                ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(2)) + unsigned(a));
                akw <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(W(1)) + unsigned(ak));
                b_tmp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(b) + (rotate_left(unsigned(akw) + unsigned(f), to_integer(unsigned(R(0))))));
            else
                ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(i)) + unsigned(a));
                akw <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(W(g_arr(i-1))) + unsigned(ak));
                b_tmp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(b) + (rotate_left(unsigned(akw) + unsigned(f), to_integer(unsigned(R(i-2))))));
            end if;
        end if;
    end process pipe_p;


    md5_f_p : process(state, a, b, c, d, i)
    begin 
        case state is
            when state_1 =>
                if i = 0 or i > 4 then
                    f <= (b and c) or ((not b) and d);
                    g <= g_arr(i);
                end if;

            when state_2 =>
            f <= (d and b) or ((not d) and c);
                g <= g_arr(i);

            when state_3 =>
                f <= b xor c xor d;
            g <= g_arr(i);

            when state_4 =>
                f <= c xor (b or (not d));
            g <= g_arr(i);

            when others =>
                f <= x"00000000";
                g <= 0;             

        end case;
    end process md5_f_p;

     md5_p : process(CLOCK_50, SW, a, b, c, d, f, g)
     begin
        if SW(17) = '0' then
            state <= start;
                i <= 0;
                a <= AA;
            b <= BB;
            c <= CC;
            d <= DD;                
            W <= (others => x"00000000");
                pad_str <= (others => x"00");
                --tmp_b := BB;
        elsif rising_edge(CLOCK_50) then
            case state is            
                when start =>

                    pad_str(0) <= in_str(0);
                    pad_str(1) <= in_str(1);
                    pad_str(2) <= in_str(2);
                    pad_str(3) <= in_str(3);
                    pad_str(4) <= in_str(4);
                    pad_str(5) <= in_str(5);
                    state <= padding;

                when padding =>
                    pad_str(6) <= "10000000";
                    pad_str(56) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(in_str'length*8, 8));
                          state <= init_w;

                when init_w =>                
                    W(0) <= pad_str(3) & pad_str(2) & pad_str(1) & pad_str(0);
                    W(1) <= pad_str(7) & pad_str(6) & pad_str(5) & pad_str(4);
                    W(14) <= pad_str(59) & pad_str(58) & pad_str(57) & pad_str(56);
                          state <= state_1;

                when state_1 =>
                          if i = 16 then
                              state <= state_2;
                          else 
                        if i > 2 then
                                    --tmp_b := b;
                                    a <= d;
                                    c <= b;
                                    d <= c;
                                    b <= b_tmp;

--                                  d <= c;
--                                  b <= b_tmp;
--                                  c <= b;
--                                  a <= d;
                                end if;
                                i <= i + 1;
                    end if;

                when state_2 =>
                    if i = 32 then
                        state <= state_3;
                          else                  
                        d <= c;
                        b <= b_tmp;
                                c <= b;
                        a <= d;
                        i <= i + 1;
                    end if;

                when state_3 =>
                    if i = 48 then
                                state <= state_4;
                          else
                        d <= c;
                        b <= b_tmp;
                                c <= b;
                        a <= d;
                        i <= i + 1;
                    end if;

                when state_4 =>
                    if i = 64 then
                                res_A <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(AA) + unsigned(a));
                                res_B <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(BB) + unsigned(b));
                                res_C <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(CC) + unsigned(c));
                                res_D <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(DD) + unsigned(d));
                                state <= done;
                    else
                        d <= c;
                        c <= b;
                                b <= b_tmp;
                        a <= d;
                        i <= i + 1;
                    end if;

                when done =>
                    state <= done;

                when others =>
                    state <= done;

            end case;
        end if;
    end process md5_p;
end architecture md5core_rtl;
```

Using this code, I get correct values for `b` in the first stage of round 0, but thereafter nothing seems to fit. As seen in this simulation, first stage in round 0 is correct, but thereafter not. This is when using `a` in this expression:

```
ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(0)) + unsigned(a)); -- using a
```

[image: simulation]

But... If I understand the second document correctly I should be using `c` instead of `a` (data forwarding), but then the first stage in round 0 doesn't work either. I.e when I do this, the first stage in round 0 gets the wrong numbers too.

```
ak <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(K(0)) + unsigned(c)); -- changed to c
```

For the particular string in the code (`helloo`) the following values are correct (first 3 stages of round 0).

```
i:0 => a:271733878, b:3679623978, c:4023233417, d:2562383102, f:2562383102, g:0
i:1 => a:2562383102, b:268703616, c:3679623978, d:4023233417, f:3421032412, g:1
i:2 => a:4023233417, b:566857930, c:268703616, d:3679623978, f:4291410697, g:2
```

By the way, `AKM` in the document is `akw` in the code.

Any tips or suggestions on bringing me in the right direction would be very appreciated. Code would be ideal. If something is unclear, I'll edit the question and try to rectify that.

Comment: Are you doing that with a microcontroller? What kind? What is your setup? Schematics? Please provide more information :-)

Comment: I have added some more info, please let me know if I can further improve it.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what you're asking for here. It would seem that you're not really all that familiar with building pipelines and related issues such as dealing with the data dependencies among the stages and getting the stages properly initialized. Teaching you that would require a book, not a web page. And I doubt that anyone who has already done a pipelined implementation of this algorithm is just going to give it to you for free. Intellectual property like that has real value.

Comment: Fair enough. You are of course right. I am not that familiar with building pipelines, only have 6 months experience with VHDL. Too be honest I wasn't hoping for much either, but when you're stuck asking for help always seems like a good option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the paper's author's comments on pipelining the algorithm. You can't just pipeline the computation for B without also pipelining the rest of the process.

I would recommend, for the purposes of getting started, that you forget about the pipeline approach altogether, and just get the algorithm working with a non-pipelined implementation of the B computation.

Once you're getting correct results, and if you need more performance, then you can look into pipelining it. Then, you'll be able to see how the intermediate results line up on each clock cycle and what it takes to keep them in sync.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have a working non-pipelined version, and the holdup regarding f(max) is the computation of b. As I understand though, is that pipelining the computation of b would be sufficient, but I guess I'll have to read it (again).

Comment: Yes. Pay particular attention to the i-1, i, i+1, i+2, etc. subscripts on all the variables, which represent stages in the pipeline for all of the variables involved. Also, there are several errors in Table 2.1 in the paper. In the third equation, the \$B_{i-1}\$ should be \$A_{i+2}\$ (which is why the variable is called AK). and in the second equation the \$M_i + 1\$ should be \$M_{i+1}\$.

Comment: Thank you! I read through it again, when you mentioned that I couldn't just pipeline `b`, did you mean what they call data forwarding in the paper (for `A`)?

Comment: Yes, that's part of it. For example, the value of \$A_{i+2}\$ is the same as \$C_i\$.

Comment: Ok, so `AK` is really `CK`. This gets more and more complex :/

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate it. I just wish I had more free time that would allow me to give you more guidance toward a solution.